# Jiffy duration in Android

Tags: android, proc

I would like to figure out a way to get jiffy duration (used by /proc) on an Android device, something similar to sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK).

My device (as  probably most of others) uses 1 centisecond (1/100s), even though /proc/timer_list reports "resolution 1 nsecs".  Is there any reliable (and preferably straightforward) way to go?

Thanks.